# Django - Is it possible to do a queryset within Count()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models

```
class Client(models.Model):
    ...

class Request(models.Model):
    ...
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to get the count of all completed requests for a queryset of clients.  The following statement gets me all the requests, but it does not check for whether the request is completed.

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(...).annotate(Count('request'))
```

What I want is this:

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(...).annotate(Count(request__completed=True))
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just use `Client.objects.filter(…).filter(request__completed=True).count()`

Comment: @RedCricket I want to keep the query results of `Client.objects.filter(…)`, and get the number of completed requests for them.

Comment: then do `clients.count()` after you query the results.

Comment: Or `len(clients)` (to avoid the extra query)

Comment: I don't think `clients.count()` would cause an extra query of the DB.

Comment: @RedCricket it absolutely does. [Check out the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

Comment: uh ... that's for `<Model>.objects.count()` not `clients.count()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Red Cricket mentioned, you could get the ***filtered count*** by dajngo's [**`count()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) method as

```
Client.objects.filter(my_otherfilters..,request__completed=True).count()
```

This will return a ***integer value*** representing the count.

---

If you want the **`QuerySet`** as well as the **`count`**,

```
qs = Client.objects.filter(my_otherfilters..,request__completed=True) # the "qs" will get the querysets
qs_count = qs.count() # "qs_count" will return the count
```

Comment: and `qs.count()` DOES NOT cause an additional transaction with the DB.

Comment: Is that a problem ?

Comment: No. I emphasized that point because of comments made under the OP where there was some confusion on that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
ModelName.objects.aggregate(Count('id'))
```

[please check the ref for more](https://github.com/monetree/movie/blob/master/bin/readme.md)